# Nearest neighbour filtering for reference image node (version 3.4)

Tags: image, pixel-art

I started Blender today with the goal of making low-poly models with pixel art/low res textures. It's just like everyone warned; very overwhelming!

A tutorial video I was watching inserted a high resolution reference image to use as a guide for making loop cuts. I tried to do the same with a pixel art image I plan to use as a texture later on, but the pixels were blurry. Normally I'd switch to a nearest neighbour filtering method to fix this issue. Google search gave me results on how to do it with model textures, but not reference images. Is there a way to change filter options for reference images?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. You could blow the image up with nearest neighbor filtering and use that instead. It will still be blurry if you zoom in far enough but it should be usable at normal zoom levels if you blow it up enough.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!